# how can i establish bgp connection using opendaylight nitrogen version (karaf-0.7.1) and my router

Tags: karaf, sdn, opendaylight, bgp

I need to establish bgp session between my router and odl. I have installed nitrogen version (karaf-0.7.1) and installed bgp feature using command feature:install odl-bgpcep-bgp.

After googling i found that in order to establish setup i need to edit a file (41-bgp-example.xml) which will be generated after installing bgp feature mentioned above, but i couldn't find the file in (\etc\opendaylight\karaf) and not seen in other locations. There is a file 31-bgp-example.xml and some other bmp file.

I am also not able to install feature (odl-bgpcep-bgp all).

What steps should be followed to do it via rest?

I installed the feature odl-restconf.

How can i proceed further? which file should i edit and how to run?

odl version: karaf(0.7.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature naming convention changed between Carbon and Nitrogen.  To install the relevant bgpcep features, install "odl-bgpcep-bgp" instead of "odl-bgpcep-bgp-all".

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the answer.Did exactly the same but still the file (41-bgp-example.xml) is not generated .Manually created the same and tried establishing bgp session but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to configure using advanced rest client (use this -localhost:8181/url).
Changed content type to application/xml.still open and notification packet(bgp) is only flowing and session is not established,ODL is sending tcp packet with reset flag set.

Comment: issue is solved.see link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145003/why-bgp-open-and-notification-packets-is-only-flowing-in-odl.