# Why bgp open and notification packets is only flowing in ODL

Tags: tcp, apache-karaf, opendaylight, bgp

I need to establish a bgp session with route reflector running  with odl and my router  and so far i have done the following. Installed opendaylight karaf ,nitrogen version .

Installed bgp features (feature:install odl-restconf odl-bgpcep-bgp,odl-bgpcep-bgp). Configured parameters using advanced rest client till bgp peer section following the official site (http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/bgp-user-guide.html).
when i checked the status of my router ,i saw that bgp state is active and In wireshark bgp open packet is send by router and odl is sending notification as connection reject .There is also a tcp packet  send with reset flag set by ODL. I enabled the debug option and checked karaf log which says .

(org.opendaylight.protocol.bgp.parser.BGPDocumentedException: BGP peer with ip: IpAddress [_ipv4Address=Ipv4Address [_value=10.10.10.2]] not configured, check configured peers in : StrictBGPPeerRegistry{peers=[]}
    at org.opendaylight.protocol.bgp.rib.impl.AbstractBGPSessionNegotiator.startNegotiation(AbstractBGPSessionNegotiator.java:103)[117:org.opendaylight.bgpcep.bgp-rib-impl:0.8.1]
    at org.opendaylight.protocol.bgp.rib.impl.AbstractBGPSessionNegotiator.channelActive(AbstractBGPSessionNegotiator.java:278)[117:org.opendaylight.bgpcep.bgp-rib-impl:0.8.1]
2018-01-04 16:46:44,191 | DEBUG | ntLoopGroup-10-3 | AbstractBGPSessionNegotiator     | 117 - org.opendaylight.bgpcep.bgp-rib-impl - 0.8.1 | Starting session negotiation on channel [id: 0xc90a1a8a, L:/10.10.10.1:179 - R:/10.10.10.2:51732]
2018-01-04 16:46:44,191 | ERROR | ntLoopGroup-10-3 | BGPDocumentedException           | 111 - org.opendaylight.bgpcep.bgp-parser-api - 0.8.1 | Error = CONNECTION_REJECTED

In short ,i want to know the following,

1) why bgp notification is send by odl with connection reject and also Tcp 
  packet send with reset flag set ?

2) why there is  no file called (41-bgp-example) generated.Still i created it manually and configured but no effects.

3) How can i proceed further to reach till route reflector, is there any thing wrong or i missed something ?

below is the file i mentioned (41-bgp-example)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- vi: set et smarttab sw=4 tabstop=4: -->
<!--
      Copyright (c) 2013 Cisco Systems, Inc. and others.  All rights reserved.
 This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which accompanies this distribution,
 and is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
-->
<snapshot>
    <required-capabilities>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:cfg?module=odl-bgp-rib-cfg&amp;revision=2013-07-01</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:spi?module=odl-bgp-rib-spi-cfg&amp;revision=2013-11-15</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl?module=odl-bgp-rib-impl-cfg&amp;revision=2013-04-09</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:topology:provider?module=odl-bgp-topology-provider-cfg&amp;revision=2013-11-15</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:reachability:ipv6?module=odl-bgp-treachability-ipv6-cfg&amp;revision=2013-11-15</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:reachability:ipv4?module=odl-bgp-treachability-ipv4-cfg&amp;revision=2013-11-15</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:binding?module=opendaylight-md-sal-binding&amp;revision=2013-10-28</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:dom?module=opendaylight-md-sal-dom&amp;revision=2013-10-28</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:netty?module=netty&amp;revision=2013-11-19</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:protocol:framework?module=protocol-framework&amp;revision=2014-03-13</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:topology?module=odl-topology-api-cfg&amp;revision=2013-11-15</capability>
        <capability>urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp-openconfig-spi?module=odl-bgp-openconfig-spi-cfg&amp;revision=2015-09-25</capability>
    </required-capabilities>
    <configuration>

        <data xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
            <modules xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:config">
                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:protocol:framework">prefix:timed-reconnect-strategy-factory</type>
                    <name>example-reconnect-strategy-factory</name>
                    <min-sleep>1000</min-sleep>
                    <max-sleep>180000</max-sleep>
                    <sleep-factor>2.00</sleep-factor>
                    <connect-time>5000</connect-time>
                    <timed-reconnect-executor>
                        <type xmlns:netty="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:netty">netty:netty-event-executor</type>
                        <name>global-event-executor</name>
                    </timed-reconnect-executor>
                </module>

                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-peer-acceptor</type>
                    <name>bgp-peer-server</name>

                    <!--Default parameters-->
                    <!-- <binding-address>127.0.0.1</binding-address> -->

                    <!--Default binding-port 179-->
                    <!-- <binding-port>1790</binding-port> -->

                    <accepting-bgp-dispatcher>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-dispatcher</type>
                        <name>global-bgp-dispatcher</name>
                    </accepting-bgp-dispatcher>
                    <accepting-peer-registry>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-peer-registry</type>
                        <name>global-bgp-peer-registry</name>
                    </accepting-peer-registry>

                </module>


                <module>
                   <type xmlns:x="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">x:bgp-application-peer</type>
                   <name>example-bgp-peer-app</name>
                   <bgp-peer-id>10.10.10.2</bgp-peer-id>
                   <target-rib>
                     <type xmlns:x="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">x:rib-instance</type>
                     <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                   </target-rib>
                   <application-rib-id>example-app-rib</application-rib-id>
                   <data-broker>
                     <type xmlns:sal="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:dom">sal:dom-async-data-broker</type>
                     <name>pingpong-broker</name>
                   </data-broker>
                </module>



                <!--
                     A single BGP peer. Note this section is deactivated because a misconfigured peer
                     tends to log rather nasty error messages.
                     For TCP-MD5 support, make sure the dispatcher associated with the rib has
                     "md5-channel-factory" attribute set and then add a "password" attribute here.
                     Note that the peer has to have the same password configured, otherwise the
                     connection will not be established.
                     If peer role is not present, default value "ibgp" will be used (allowed values are also "ebgp" and
                     "rr-client").
                   -->

                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-peer</type>
                    <name>example-bgp-peer</name>
                    <host>10.10.10.1</host>
                    <holdtimer>180</holdtimer>
                    <peer-role>ibgp</peer-role>
                    <rib>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:rib-instance</type>
                        <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                    </rib>
                    <peer-registry>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-peer-registry</type>
                        <name>global-bgp-peer-registry</name>
                    </peer-registry>
                    <advertized-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv4-unicast</name>
                    </advertized-table>
                    <advertized-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv6-unicast</name>
                    </advertized-table>
                    <advertized-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>linkstate</name>
                    </advertized-table>
                    <advertized-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv4-flowspec</name>
                    </advertized-table>
                    <advertized-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv6-flowspec</name>
                    </advertized-table>
                    <advertized-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>labeled-unicast</name>
                    </advertized-table>
                </module>

                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:rib-impl</type>
                    <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                    <rib-id>example-bgp-rib</rib-id>
                    <local-as>65530</local-as>
                    <bgp-rib-id>10.10.10.2</bgp-rib-id>
                    <!-- if cluster-id is not present, it's value is the same as bgp-id -->
                    <!-- <cluster-id>192.0.2.3</cluster-id> -->
                    <local-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv4-unicast</name>
                    </local-table>
                    <local-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv6-unicast</name>
                    </local-table>
                    <local-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>linkstate</name>
                    </local-table>
                    <local-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv4-flowspec</name>
                    </local-table>
                    <local-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>ipv6-flowspec</name>
                    </local-table>
                    <local-table>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-table-type</type>
                        <name>labeled-unicast</name>
                    </local-table>
                    <extensions>
                        <type xmlns:ribspi="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:spi">ribspi:extensions</type>
                        <name>global-rib-extensions</name>
                    </extensions>
                    <bgp-dispatcher>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:bgp-dispatcher</type>
                        <name>global-bgp-dispatcher</name>
                    </bgp-dispatcher>
                    <data-provider>
                        <type xmlns:binding="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:binding">binding:binding-async-data-broker</type>
                        <name>pingpong-binding-data-broker</name>
                    </data-provider>
                    <dom-data-provider>
                        <type xmlns:sal="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:dom">sal:dom-async-data-broker</type>
                        <name>pingpong-broker</name>
                    </dom-data-provider>
                    <codec-tree-factory>
                        <type xmlns:binding="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:binding">binding:binding-codec-tree-factory</type>
                        <name>runtime-mapping-singleton</name>
                    </codec-tree-factory>
                    <session-reconnect-strategy>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:protocol:framework">prefix:reconnect-strategy-factory</type>
                        <name>example-reconnect-strategy-factory</name>
                    </session-reconnect-strategy>
                    <tcp-reconnect-strategy>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:protocol:framework">prefix:reconnect-strategy-factory</type>
                        <name>example-reconnect-strategy-factory</name>
                    </tcp-reconnect-strategy>
                    <openconfig-provider>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp-openconfig-spi">prefix:bgp-openconfig-provider</type>
                        <name>openconfig-bgp</name>
                    </openconfig-provider>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:reachability:ipv4">prefix:bgp-reachability-ipv4</type>
                    <name>example-ipv4-topology</name>
                    <data-provider>
                        <type xmlns:binding="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:binding">binding:binding-async-data-broker</type>
                        <name>pingpong-binding-data-broker</name>
                    </data-provider>
                    <local-rib>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:cfg">prefix:rib</type>
                        <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                    </local-rib>
                    <topology-id>example-ipv4-topology</topology-id>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:reachability:ipv6">prefix:bgp-reachability-ipv6</type>
                    <name>example-ipv6-topology</name>
                    <data-provider>
                        <type xmlns:binding="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:binding">binding:binding-async-data-broker</type>
                        <name>pingpong-binding-data-broker</name>
                    </data-provider>
                    <local-rib>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:cfg">prefix:rib</type>
                        <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                    </local-rib>
                    <topology-id>example-ipv6-topology</topology-id>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:topology:provider">prefix:bgp-linkstate-topology</type>
                    <name>example-linkstate-topology</name>
                    <data-provider>
                        <type xmlns:binding="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:binding">binding:binding-async-data-broker</type>
                        <name>pingpong-binding-data-broker</name>
                    </data-provider>
                    <local-rib>
                        <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:cfg">prefix:rib</type>
                        <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                    </local-rib>
                    <topology-id>example-linkstate-topology</topology-id>
                </module>
            </modules>

            <services xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:config">
                <service>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:protocol:framework">prefix:reconnect-strategy-factory</type>
                    <instance>
                        <name>example-reconnect-strategy-factory</name>
                        <provider>/config/modules/module[name='timed-reconnect-strategy-factory']/instance[name='example-reconnect-strategy-factory']</provider>
                    </instance>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:topology">prefix:topology-reference</type>
                    <instance>
                        <name>example-ipv4-topology</name>
                        <provider>/config/modules/module[name='bgp-reachability-ipv4']/instance[name='example-ipv4-topology']</provider>
                    </instance>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:cfg">prefix:rib</type>
                    <instance>
                        <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                        <provider>/config/modules/module[name='rib-impl']/instance[name='example-bgp-rib']</provider>
                    </instance>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:bgp:rib:impl">prefix:rib-instance</type>
                    <instance>
                        <name>example-bgp-rib</name>
                        <provider>/config/modules/module[name='rib-impl']/instance[name='example-bgp-rib']</provider>
                    </instance>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:topology">prefix:topology-reference</type>
                    <instance>
                        <name>example-ipv6-topology</name>
                        <provider>/config/modules/module[name='bgp-reachability-ipv6']/instance[name='example-ipv6-topology']</provider>
                    </instance>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <type xmlns:prefix="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:topology">prefix:topology-reference</type>
                    <instance>
                        <name>example-linkstate-topology</name>
                        <provider>/config/modules/module[name='bgp-linkstate-topology']/instance[name='example-linkstate-topology']</provider>
                    </instance>
                </service>
            </services>
        </data>
    </configuration>
</snapshot>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: The file 41-bgp-example  will not be generated since the config subsystem has changed in  the Nitrogen version.so you have to do via REST.But that too didn't worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer for the first couple of questions

1) why bgp notification is send by odl with connection reject and also Tcp packet send with reset flag set ?

ans:- because peer was not properly configured.Using rest client, configuration was not completely successful, so edited manually file  protocols-config.xml(in path  /etc/opendaylight/bgp) and after this it worked.

2) why there is no file called (41-bgp-example) generated.Still i created it manually and configured but no effects.

ans:The file will not be generated because for nitrogen version,the config sub system has changed and hence have to follow using REST.